# In Android what does it mean, "FirebaseApp was not initialized with a bucket name."?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made this code to upload image to firebase with a child directory "photos".

I found this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp was not initialized with a bucket name.

```
    public class Firebase extends AppCompatActivity {
        public TextView text1;
        public Button button1;
        public Button button2;
        public StorageReference mStorage;
        public ProgressDialog mProgress;
        public static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
        public static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://ivepos.firebaseio.com/weather";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(firebase);
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_INTENT);

                }        
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                mProgress.setMessage("Uploading...");
                mProgress.show();
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(Firebase.this, "Upload done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: By the way, please try to create a [mcve]. The image  code seems unrelated to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `google-services.json` may not contain the Firebase Storage URL. This is possible if you downloaded the file right after creating the project, since creating the bucket may take a few moments.

The solution is to download the latest `google-services.json` from the Firebase Cosnole, drop it into your project's app directory, and rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your storage bucket setting.

Comment: What should I change in setting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a secondary Firebase project . SetStorageBucket value from the google-service.json

```
val options1 = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(data.apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(data.appID)
            .setProjectId(data.projectID)
            .setStorageBucket(data.storageURL)
            .setDatabaseUrl(data.databaseURL)
            .build()
        

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options1, "agencyDB")
```